# Missing reflection

Tags: nethack

I'm a level 13 knight. I went through mines end and sobokan. I went until dlvl 15 but then, I get a lot of attack from magic missile, cold and fire wand/spell. Any advice for me to obtain reflection?

Answer (score 2):

After some research, here's a few solutions to look at :

- Wish for it
- Polypile and hope i'll get the amulet or the shield
- Aleax avec 25% chance of having one.
- Statue of Perseus on Medusa level has 25% chance to have one.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get reflection from Silver Dragon Scale Mail, via enchant armor on Silver scales, or by wish (much better wish than shield because of hi AC and enchantment).  Finding dragons or eggs may be bothersome, but there are places they can be found (Castle, Ft. Ludios , etc.), and they can be reverse genocided, if you happen to find that scroll (cursed, mind you). Be prepared to fight more than one, have cold resistance, and maybe a way to turn undead if no scale drops the first time.

Answer (score 0):

The best one for a knight would be to probably find a mirror shield.  However in a rogue-like there's no guaranteed place to get one aside from using a wish to get it.